# How can I shorten HH:MM:SS as much as possible?

Tags: scripting, date

Suppose I have the following syntax: `HH:MM:SS`. I want to make it as short as possible. For example, I want "00:00:30" To turn into "30". Similarly, I want "0:30:00" to turn into "30:00". How can I do this with shell commands?

Comment: What output you would expect with 00:00:00.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I understand you need to remove the leading zeroes, so let's suppose you have a file like this

```
00:00:30
00:01:30
00:30:00
01:30:00
30:00:00
```

would become

```
30
1:30
30:00
1:30:00
30:00:00
```

If that's so, you just need to apply a `sed` command like this:

```
sed 's/^[0:]*//' file
```

Comment: Consider adding `00:00:00` to the example. I read "as much as possible" and my formal brain totally enjoys what happens to this exact string. :D

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Good one :), I' d guess it would be 0... asked to OP.

Comment: Why, though? You would save a tiny amount of storage space and guarantee that your result was non-standard…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin probably for user-friendly display instead of for storage?

Comment: Non-sortable as well.

Comment: @justhalf user-friendly in most cases would take into account appropriate precision and give things like "30m" or "30s".  Still non-sortable of course.  Also this could be set up to always fit in 3 character, and compressing to known space is often more useful than truncation - but we don't know what the OP is doing with the data.

Comment: @reinierpost I'd also be very reluctant to lose sortability, but perhaps there's always a sort by something else. After all this looks like a duration and sorting by duration probably isn't a high priority. With right-justification (thinking spreadsheet-like display, as just padding back out with spaces would seem like a waste) you'd still get the scale from the length, while the seconds would line up.

Comment: If you want the "00:00:00" → "0" case to be handled too: ` sed -e 's/^[0:]*//' -e 's/^$/0/'` - this will cause an empty string to be turned back into a single zero. There're probably more ways to achieve this.

Comment: @Amasrakon, can you say anything about why you're doing this, please? Either way, would I be wrong to reword the Question as "How to strip out all the leadings zeroes, irrespective of colons?"

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin This is the answer, I understand that you are asking OP. You should post the comments in [the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/707048/338177).

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Thanks and I think SE works on Members Posting Comments to the latest (useful) stage of the discussion… not by ignoring everything that's happened since the OQ.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Oh, I thought OP wouldn't be notified. Good to know then :)

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Thanks and my belief is that the OP is notified of every Post, and the rest of us only when someone uses @…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin mmmh... if you are not sure I'm beginning to doubt that then, if a post had 20 answers OP would have too many notifications if each has its own discussion in comments. I don't remember in my own questions if I received notifications from answers.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity If you mind, look it up in SE Help, why not?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I did! Found an old question (12 years) regarding a feature request of precisely that. I didn't dig any deeper though. It may be a good question to ask if it hasn't. But I think the whole point of the 'following' feature is to decide what posts you want to get notified of, whether you are the asker or the answerer.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity You might be wholly right there and either way, jolly good luck to you!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin To you as well!